# Envelope Issue in Net::SMTP ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp

I am using this code to send email using ruby and SMTP protocol

```
smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'smtp.gmail.com', 587
smtp.enable_starttls
smtp.start('smtp.gmail.com', 'username', 'password', :login)
msgstr = "From: Sender <Sender@gmail.com>
      To: Receiver <receiver@gmail.com>
      Subject: Spammers List

          This is a test message"
smtp.send_message(msgstr, 'sender@gmail.com', 'receiver@gmail.com')
smtp.finish
```

But the envelope comes together.There is no To and Subject in the received mail.Everything comes in From part itself like this.
    Sender  To: Receiver Subject: Spammers List

Can anybody say me what is the error in the code?

Comment: In RFC822, indentation in a header indicates that it is a continuation of the previous header line.  So the value of your `msgstr` really does contain a long `From:` header with all that stuff in it, wrapped over several physical lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have 2 problems. SMTP requires cr-lf linefeeds, and headers can't have leading spaces. I'm not certain of this point, but I think the last message line might also need to end with a newline.  Does it work if you build the content as...

```
msgstr = <<SMTP
From: Sender <Sender@gmail.com>\r
To: Receiver <receiver@gmail.com>\r
Subject: Spammers List\r
\r
This is a test message\r
SMTP
```

Comment: Im writing the code as a definition of a function.So I need to have the indentation.So I used msgstr = <<-SMTP . But still it displays the same as previous.

Comment: Using `<<-SMTP` lets you indent the closing `SMTP` if that's important to you, but I presume you are not attempting to indent the contents, because that will not work. Also, I did just fix a minor error in my answer (that probably won't help, but...) since "here" strings always have a trailing newline, I didn't need the last blank line, and if left in, it should have contained a `\r`.

Comment: Or you could use indentation in the definition, but then remove it programmatically before you use the string.  The basic answer is that you cannot have that indentation there because it will break the RFC822 message format.